# How to run a method before form is closed?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, formclosing

I want my Windows Forms application to be disconnected from the server before user close the form. Hence, I use FormClosing event;

```
FormClosing += FormManager_FormClosing;
```

I tried something with Backgroundworker or without Backgroundworker, but it did not work properly.

Code I wrote;

```
public partial class MqttManager : Form
    {
        MqttHandler mqttHandler = new MqttHandler();
        ...
        public MqttManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ...
            // Specify what will happen while form is closing.
            FormClosing += MqttManager_FormClosing;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Disconnect from the broker while form is closing.
        /// </summary>
        private void MqttManager_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isDisconnected = mqttHandler.Disconnect();
            while (!isDisconnected)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            //disconnBgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void disconnBgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            statusPctBox.WaitOnLoad = false;
            statusPctBox.Image = Properties.Resources.bigCircle;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        private void disconnBgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(
            object sender,
            RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isDisconnected = mqttHandler.Disconnect();
            if (isDisconnected)
            {
                statusPctBox.Image = Properties.Resources.x32;
                flag = true;
            }
            else
                statusPctBox.Image = Properties.Resources.ok32;
        }
    }

class MqttHandler
    {
        ...
        public MqttHandler() { }
        ...

        /// <summary>
        /// Disconnect from the broker.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Disconnect()
        {
            try
            {
                client.Disconnect();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** "While (!isDisconnected)" is used, I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object." message after form is closed.

**SOLUTION:** First of all, thanks for all of you. I found my mistake on code. After disconnection, an event handler was fired and tried to change UI element with "Invoke". An error was happened at that moment. To handle this problem, I removed related event handler from related object after disconnection.

Comment: Not sure why the need for a thread in the first place.  Just disconnect in `MqttManager_FormClosing`

Comment: Aside did you try to use whlie (!isDisconnected) instead of  if (!isDisconnected) already? (naturally setting isDisconnected inside the while again after each thread.sleep)

Comment: Not sure what the BGW has to do with the question either. It isn't called in the `FormClosing` event, or anywhere else. Just what is the actual requirement? If you want to cancel closing, just set `e.Cancel`. If you want to wait, use `await Task.Delay();`, *not* Thread.Sleep or BGW. If you want to retry, you only need a loop with `Task.Delay();`. Doing the same with BGW would be *very* complex.

Comment: Note that unless MqttHandler is multithreaded, Thread.Sleep will freeze it and prevent it from receiving an answer. This won't happen with `await Task.Delay();`

Comment: Also note that if you really want to close the connection, `MqttHandler` should implement IDisposable, and get disposed in the form's Dispose method. This way the connection will be closed even if an exception occurs or you forget to close it in code. It's the same as using a database connection. In fact, your client may already work this way

Comment: What MQTT client library are you using? What .NET version?  It may have asynchronous equivalents of `Disconnect` that make disconnection on form closing much easier

Comment: @Thomas, I use "while" but I wrote in question "if". I've corrected the question.

Comment: @Micky, if there is only disconnect in MqttManager_FormClosing, then I get System.ObjectDisposedException as I tell in edit part of question.

Comment: @séan35 if oyu use while you have to also put isDisconnected = mqttHandler.Disconnect(); inside the while statement else you have a nice endless loop

Comment: Thanks for all of you, I found my mistake. I've edited the question with my solution.